# How to filter queries by using other queries in django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to apply a filter using another queryset as the filter parameter.
    para = Parameters.objects.filter(*somecode*)

Now this *para* is to be used as a parameter for another filter. Something like (I know this won't work, but)
    qs = Colums.objects.filter(fieldname = para)

As in *qs* should have objects from para[0] and para[1]. I tried to concatenate by for loop but I couldn't work it out.

Is there any way I can get *qs* as a combined results of para[0] and para[1]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if para is FK ~>

```
qs = Colum.objects.filter (para__in = para)
```

just use a value of para: ex: para.name

```
para_ids = Parameters.objects.filter(somecode).values_list('id', flat=True)
# and replace in the upper case
```